# Adding values to text boxes at runtime c# .NET

Tags: mp4

How to add values of the textboxes on change event of the textboxes? 
Thanks.

Comment: @y0io he didn't say it was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a telerik output for you

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1
{
private int iTotal;
//// add remaining TextBoxes here.
private void myCoolTextBoxes_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    iTotal = 0;
    //// reset.
    //// loop thru all controls on Form.
    foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls) {
        //// locate TextBoxes that .Name.StartsWith...
        if (ctl is TextBox & ctl.Name.StartsWith("TxtPPproduct")) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctl.Text))
                iTotal += Convert.ToInt32(ctl.Text);
            //// if not a empty value in TextBox, add to Total.
        }
    }
    txtTOTAL.Text = Convert.ToString(iTotal);
    //// Display total in your TOTAL TextBox.
}
```

}

Note: Make sure you set telerik to 'vb to c#' and not 'c# to vb' so it doesn't give an error....